# C++ main program with a thread requires Ctrl+C twice in order to exit

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, signals

I am running the below C++ program, with a thread inside it on Ubuntu.
Why does it require two Ctrl+C calls in order to quit the program?
I notice that the first Ctrl+C I issue to it only closes myThread.

NOTE: I am sure that myThread thread ceases to exist after the first Ctrl+C. This I found by doing ps aux. And I get the print `main_recv_sigint: Executed` only after the second Ctrl+C
In my production code, I am excuting a python code instead of `sleep 1000`

How can I have a single Ctrl+C close it completely?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <signal.h>
#include <thread>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "unistd.h"
#include <cstdio>

void *myThread(void *params)
{
    std::string cmd = "sleep 1000";
    if (system (cmd.c_str ()));

    return NULL;
}

void main_recv_sigint (int sig);
bool runMainThread = true;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t threadID;
    pthread_create(&threadID, NULL, myThread, NULL);

    signal(SIGINT, main_recv_sigint);

    while (runMainThread) {
        while (runMainThread)
            sleep(2);

        if (!runMainThread)
            break;
    }

    printf("Waiting for myThread() to exit\n");
    pthread_join(threadID, NULL);
    printf("Wait for myThread() exit done\n");

    return 0;
}

void main_recv_sigint (int sig)
{
    printf("main_recv_sigint: Executed\n");
    runMainThread = false;
    return;
}
```

Comment: As a sidenote, if you use pthreads, then you should include the header which declares the API.

Comment: it's really not a good idea to do ` printf("main_recv_sigint: Executed\n"); ` in a signal handler.

Comment: I see. I am putting printing statements mainly for being able to debug this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things explain this behavior:

1. `system` [causes the calling process to ignore SIGINT](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/system.html) while waiting for its child to terminate
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> sends a SIGINT to the entire foreground process group, which includes both your program and its child *sleep*

So, the first <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> kills the child *sleep* process but is ignored by the parent — the handler is never invoked — which continues to loop unaware.  The second <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> delivers a SIGINT which is handled by the parent as you expect.

As for your second question, *"How can I have a single Ctrl+C close it completely?"*, you'll need to redesign.  `system` is an old function, designed without threads in mind, a bit idiosyncratic, and probably not appropriate for your use case.

Comment: note that replacing the `system` call with a `sleep(1000)` would still not properly end the process on a Ctrl+C, because the signal handler doesn't actually end the thread - it just ends the `while` loop in `main`.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker, right but I don't think the OP will do that.  (Surely the `sleep 1000` is simply a stand-in for some long-running external process.)

Comment: that long-running process would probably also have to be interrupted by the signal handler, same as with the sleep. The main point being that the signal handler as it stands now is not sufficient for a Ctrl+C to close the process completely (which is what the OP wants) - the signal handler would also have to interrupt and close any threads and child processes in whatever way is appropriate.

Comment: In my actual code, I am using system to call a python script. How could I do that with system? Any ideas on that..